# Which approach to use for passing arguments to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am learning about `Fragment` in Android development. So the question is which approach is better to use for passing arguments from an `Activity` to a `Fragment`:

```
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

or

```
MyFragment.newInstance(args);
```

Or it does not matter which one to use? Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `MyFragment.newInstance(args)` is static, it use `setArguments()` to pass arguments to the instance of Fragment.

Instantiate a fragment using `newInstance()` is a good practice in most cases for creating Fragment.

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int someInt) {
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", someInt);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

See: [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)